# How can I fetch all the new users that are created on all Stack Exchange sites via Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, api

Is it possible to fetch all the new user accounts that are created (from some date) on all Stack Exchange sites via the Stack Exchange API?

And how can it be done?

Comment: There are currently about [176 Stack Exchange sites](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/Stack_Exchange_sites_2020-11-20_body.html) (MSE counted, but not [Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/area51/info), [https://stackexchange.com/](https://stackexchange.com/) (not sure about its name), and meta sites (except MSE)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API is always per site. There is no overall API.

Call per main site:

[`/users#fromdate=2020-11-15&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!bWX4*A7B1t*_Y5`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#fromdate=2020-11-15&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!bWX4*A7B1t*_Y5&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

and then combine results.

Here is a proof of concept for loading from 3 sites, 2 pages of 15 users with a creationdate of 2020-11-15.

Additions to be made by the reader: fetch all sites from the [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) endpoint, fetch all users, select a specific date, register for a key to allow for 20,000 calls per day and have less throttling.

```js
var sites = ['stackoverflow', 'superuser', 'math'];

var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';
var endpoint = 'users';
var query = {
 'fromdate' : 1605398400, 
 'order': 'desc',
 'sort': 'creation',
 'site': 'stackoverflow',
 'filter': '!bWX4*A7B1t*_Y5'
 };
 
 function buildUrl(site, page) {
   query.site = site;
   query.page = page;
   var qs = Object.keys(query).reduce((a,i) => (a === undefined?'':a+'&') + i + '=' + query[i]);
   return url + endpoint + '?' + qs;
 }
 
 function usercard(user) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', user.link);
  a.innerHTML  = user.display_name;
  return a; 
 }
 
 function appendUsers(items) {
   var users = document.getElementById('users');
   for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      users.appendChild(usercard(item));
    }
 }
 
 function error(msg) {
  document.getElementById('error').textContent = msg;
 }
 
 function loadForSite(site) {
   var page = 1;
   if (site === undefined) return;
   
   var users = document.getElementById('users');
   users.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
   
   function loadPage() {
     fetch(buildUrl(site, page)).then((data) => {    
       data.json().then( json => {
         var backoff = (json.backoff || 1) * 1200; // go easy, always
         if (json.error_message) {
           error(json.error_message);
         } else {
           if (json.has_more && page < 2) { // needs better handling
             page++;
             setTimeout(loadPage, backoff);
           } else {
             setTimeout(loadNextSite, backoff);
           }
           appendUsers(json.items || []);
         }
       }).catch(_=>{error('response error');});  
     }).catch(_=>{error('fetch error');});
   }
   loadPage();
 }
 
 function loadNextSite() {
  loadForSite(sites.pop());
 }
 
 loadNextSite();
```

```css
a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "error"></div>
<div id = "users"></div>
```

Comment: Is there an overall rate limit or is that also independent?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Rate limits for the SE API are based on either the IP from which requests are made and/or the user/app whose auth token is being used in the request, depending on which rate limit it is that you might be hitting. Which site your request is about has no impact on rate limits. For more details see [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).